# Modify text after post count

Tags: archives, categories, count

On my Archives page, I list categories with post counts. I've modified the post count by removing the parentheses, wrapping them in a span that floats them to the right, and putting the word "Entries" after each post count. But I'd like the text after the count to change for categories with only a single post (i.e. "Entry" instead of "Entries").

My current code for this is:

```
<?php
$variable = wp_list_categories('title_li=&echo=0&show_count=1');
$variable = str_replace( '(', '<span class="cat-count">', $variable);
$variable = str_replace( ')', ' Entries</span>', $variable);
echo $variable;
?>
```

How can I modify this so that categories with 1 post say "1 Entry" and those with more than 1 say "X Entries"?

You can see my Archives page [here](http://womopage.net/sandbox/archives/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_n()` function will sort out single from plural. How to use it is in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_n).

**EDIT:**
Apologies. My first go at an answer wasn't quite enough to get you there. The trouble with using `wp_list_categories()` in this context is that it prints out pre-formatted HTML and you don't end up with any value you can use for $count.

Instead, try using [`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) which will return an array of category objects you can tap into to get post counts and display accordingly.

Something like the following should do the trick, or at least get you started:

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories();
echo '<ul>';
    foreach($categories as $category) { 
        echo '<li><span class="cat-count"><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name.'</a>'; 
        echo ' ' . $category->count . _n(' Entry', ' Entries', $category->count ) . '</span></li>';
    } 
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: So, I need something like: _n( '1 Entry', '%s Entries', $count ), right? But I don't know how or where to add that to the code I already have. (Sorry, I only know enough PHP to get into trouble.)

Comment: I've updated my response above. Hope it's a little more helpful now.